# Como configurar o Driver de envio de emails no Laravel com remetente dinâmico

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, email, smtp

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Senha123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Como deixar `MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com` e `MAIL_PASSWORD=Senha123` de acordo com os dados do usuário que está logado.

Comment: Está usando qual versão do laravel ?

Comment: Olá, a versão é 5.5.36

Answer (score -1):

Olá, eu estou conseguindo enviar o email certinho, o único problema é que além destas configurações que você citou, que já estão feita, ainda é necessário fazer a configuração no arquivo .env, e la devem ser colocados estes dados.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=Senha123 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

O email remetente vai ser sempre o colocado MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com , é o que preciso deixar de acordo com o usuário logado, enão ter que colcoar um email fixo ali.